# knockout value assignment does not work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i have to get a value from my REST service and assign it to knockout observable

the code looks like

```
   mydata=$.ajax({ url: 'http://myserver:7101/MUDRESTService/rest/v1/mudstats?onlyData=true',             
             type: 'get',  
             dataType: 'json',    
             success: function(output) {     

                   dailyMinRest = JSON.parse(mydata.responseText).items[0].AvgSession;
                   console.log(dailyMinRest)
                  sessionCountRest = JSON.parse(mydata.responseText).items[0].Sessions;
             }        
           });

           self.dailyMin = ko.observable(dailyMinRest);
```

the problem is with the last line. if i keep here the obviously there is no guranteed for it to execute after rest returns the response. however, if i move it to inside the succss method then the self variable is not resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Create the `dailyMin` observable immediately and then update it when your ajax request completes by calling the observable and passing in the new value:

```
self.dailyMin = ko.observable();
mydata=$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myserver:7101/MUDRESTService/rest/v1/mudstats?onlyData=true',
    type: 'get',  
    dataType: 'json',    
    success: function(output) {
        self.dailyMin(JSON.parse(mydata.responseText).items[0].AvgSession);
    }
});
```

BTW, I'm not sure why you're calling `JSON.parse(mydata.responseText)` instead of using the already parsed JSON response in `output`, but I'll assume you know what you're doing there :-).